# ¿Como quitar el usuario y la contraseña al consultar mi aplicación en el navegador?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, webforms, navegador-web

Hola espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de antemano gracias.

Tengo una aplicacion web en asp.net con webforms, al momento de consultar esta pagina en el navegador me aparece una alerta pidiendo mi nombre de usuario de windows y contraseña al introducirla me la vuelve a pedir como si esta fuera incorrecta y por tanto no puedo visualizar mi aplicación. Esta ventana me aparece en todos los navegadores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe como puedo quitar esa alerta para poder consultar mi aplicación sin que me pida credenciales?.

Comment: Agregaste algun tipo de credenciales a tu app? si no, no deberia pedirte nada. y si la agregaste vos, no creo que podamos ayudarte salvo que las saques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa ventana tiene que ver con la seguridad integrada de windows que se configura cuando creas el sitio web en el IIS

Tiene que ver con esta opcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Windows Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/)

Tambien se puede configurar desde el `web.config` valida si tienes

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Leandro efectivamente tengo este codigo en mi webconfig **<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>** he comentado el de autenticacion modo windows pero aun así me sigue apareciendo la alerta.

Comment: recuerda que no solo en el web.config, valida como se configura la seguridad en el IIS, porque puede que este aun este solicitando la seguridad de windows